# How to make Moose attributes immutable?

Tags: perl, immutability, moose

I would like to have immutable attributes in Moose. 'ro' takes care of this for scalar values and references, however, the inner workings of the reference are not affected by this write protection.
This being Perl, there must be a way around this …

```
package SomeClass;
use Moose;

has 'list' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => 'ArrayRef',
);

package main;

use warnings; use strict;
use v5.36;
use feature qw(try);
no warnings qw(experimental::try);
use Data::Printer;

my $x = SomeClass->new({
    list => [qw(a b c)]
});

# how do I disallow this?
push $x->list()->@*, 'd';

p $x;

#list   [
#            [0] "a",
#            [1] "b",
#            [2] "c",
#            [3] "d"
#        ]
```

But I'd like a behavior akin to:

```
use Const::Fast;
const my $LIST => [qw(x y z)];

try {
    push $LIST->@*, 'no way';
} catch ($e) {
    warn $e;
}

# Modification of a read-only value attempted at ... line ...
# [
#     [0] "x" (read-only),
#     [1] "y" (read-only),
#     [2] "z" (read-only)
# ] (read-only) (read-only)

p $LIST;
```

Comment: The object is immutable. It's something referenced by the object (the array) that isn't. You will need to make *that* immutable. You already demonstrated you know how to do that (in your second snippet).

Comment: To get the most out of classes with immutable objects, overload `=` for that class.

Comment: So, you mean, I should simply pass the const reference to the constructor?`SomeClass->new({list => $SOME_CONST})`. That would work - but would not carry any guarantee. I wonder if one could use coercion to convert a plain reference to a readonly one that way...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean with the overload, though.

Comment: Re "*I should simply pass the const reference to the constructor?*", You could. Or you could make a copy in the constructor. Shallow or deep? That's up to you. Or yeah, a coercion. But that would require testing for readonly, and that gets complicated if you want it to be read-only deeply.

Comment: https://perldoc.perl.org/overload, specifically https://perldoc.perl.org/overload#Copy-Constructor